# bundler: failed to load command: jekyll and undefined method `relative_directory' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, jekyll

When running `bundle exec jekyll serve` I get `bundler: failed to load command: jekyll`

My environments:

```
macOS 12.0.1
jekyll 4.2.2
ruby 3.1.2p20 (2022-04-12 revision 4491bb740a) [x86_64-darwin21]
```

`bundle exec jekyll serve --trace` gives me:

```
bundler: failed to load command: jekyll (/Users/Sixian/.gem/ruby/2.7.1/bin/jekyll)
/Users/Sixian/my-digital-garden/_plugins/empty_front_matter_note_injector.rb:11:in `block in <top (required)>': undefined method `relative_directory' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

  Dir.glob(site.collections['notes'].relative_directory + '/**/*.md').each do |filename|
                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        from /Users/Sixian/.gem/ruby/2.7.1/gems/jekyll-4.2.2/lib/jekyll/hooks.rb:103:in `block in trigger'
        from /Users/Sixian/.gem/ruby/2.7.1/gems/jekyll-4.2.2/lib/jekyll/hooks.rb:102:in `each'
        from /Users/Sixian/.gem/ruby/2.7.1/gems/jekyll-4.2.2/lib/jekyll/hooks.rb:102:in `trigger'
        from /Users/Sixian/.gem/ruby/2.7.1/gems/jekyll-4.2.2/lib/jekyll/site.rb:38:in `initialize'
        from /Users/Sixian/.gem/ruby/2.7.1/gems/jekyll-4.2.2/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:30:in `new'
        from /Users/Sixian/.gem/ruby/2.7.1/gems/jekyll-4.2.2/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:30:in `process'
        from /Users/Sixian/.gem/ruby/2.7.1/gems/jekyll-4.2.2/lib/jekyll/command.rb:91:in `block in process_with_graceful_fail'
        from /Users/Sixian/.gem/ruby/2.7.1/gems/jekyll-4.2.2/lib/jekyll/command.rb:91:in `each'
        from /Users/Sixian/.gem/ruby/2.7.1/gems/jekyll-4.2.2/lib/jekyll/command.rb:91:in `process_with_graceful_fail'
        from /Users/Sixian/.gem/ruby/2.7.1/gems/jekyll-4.2.2/lib/jekyll/commands/serve.rb:86:in `block (2 levels) in init_with_program'
        from /Users/Sixian/.gem/ruby/2.7.1/gems/mercenary-0.4.0/lib/mercenary/command.rb:221:in `block in execute'
        from /Users/Sixian/.gem/ruby/2.7.1/gems/mercenary-0.4.0/lib/mercenary/command.rb:221:in `each'
        from /Users/Sixian/.gem/ruby/2.7.1/gems/mercenary-0.4.0/lib/mercenary/command.rb:221:in `execute'
        from /Users/Sixian/.gem/ruby/2.7.1/gems/mercenary-0.4.0/lib/mercenary/program.rb:44:in `go'
        from /Users/Sixian/.gem/ruby/2.7.1/gems/mercenary-0.4.0/lib/mercenary.rb:21:in `program'
        from /Users/Sixian/.gem/ruby/2.7.1/gems/jekyll-4.2.2/exe/jekyll:15:in `<top (required)>'
        from /Users/Sixian/.gem/ruby/2.7.1/bin/jekyll:25:in `load'
        from /Users/Sixian/.gem/ruby/2.7.1/bin/jekyll:25:in `<top (required)>'
        from /Users/Sixian/.gem/ruby/2.7.1/gems/bundler-2.3.18/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:58:in `load'
        from /Users/Sixian/.gem/ruby/2.7.1/gems/bundler-2.3.18/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:58:in `kernel_load'
        from /Users/Sixian/.gem/ruby/2.7.1/gems/bundler-2.3.18/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:23:in `run'
        from /Users/Sixian/.gem/ruby/2.7.1/gems/bundler-2.3.18/lib/bundler/cli.rb:483:in `exec'
        from /Users/Sixian/.gem/ruby/2.7.1/gems/bundler-2.3.18/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        from /Users/Sixian/.gem/ruby/2.7.1/gems/bundler-2.3.18/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
        from /Users/Sixian/.gem/ruby/2.7.1/gems/bundler-2.3.18/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
        from /Users/Sixian/.gem/ruby/2.7.1/gems/bundler-2.3.18/lib/bundler/cli.rb:31:in `dispatch'
        from /Users/Sixian/.gem/ruby/2.7.1/gems/bundler-2.3.18/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:485:in `start'
        from /Users/Sixian/.gem/ruby/2.7.1/gems/bundler-2.3.18/lib/bundler/cli.rb:25:in `start'
        from /Users/Sixian/.gem/ruby/2.7.1/gems/bundler-2.3.18/exe/bundle:48:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from /Users/Sixian/.gem/ruby/2.7.1/gems/bundler-2.3.18/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:120:in `with_friendly_errors'
        from /Users/Sixian/.gem/ruby/2.7.1/gems/bundler-2.3.18/exe/bundle:36:in `<top (required)>'
        from /Users/Sixian/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
        from /Users/Sixian/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
```

`gem env` gives me:

```
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 3.3.11
  - RUBY VERSION: 3.1.2 (2022-04-12 patchlevel 20) [x86_64-darwin21]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/Sixian/.gem/ruby/2.7.1
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/Sixian/.gem/ruby/3.1.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/ruby
  - GIT EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/bin/git
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/Sixian/.gem/ruby/2.7.1/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/Sixian/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/3.1.2/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
     - ruby
     - x86_64-darwin-21
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/Sixian/.gem/ruby/2.7.1
     - /Users/Sixian/.rubies/ruby-2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - "gem" => "--no-document"
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /Users/Sixian/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/bin
     - /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin
     - /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/bin
     - /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin
     - /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/bin
     - /Users/Sixian/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/bin
     - /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin
     - /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/bin
     - /Users/Sixian/.gem/ruby/2.7.0/bin
     - /Users/Sixian/.gem/ruby/2.7.1/bin
     - /Users/Sixian/.rubies/ruby-2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/bin
     - /Users/Sixian/.rubies/ruby-2.7.1/bin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /Users/Sixian/.bin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/bin
     - /bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /sbin
     - /Users/Sixian/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/bin
     - /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin
     - /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/bin
     - /Users/Sixian/.gem/ruby/2.7.0/bin
     - /Users/Sixian/.bin
```

I had wanted to create another blog-like page which will be fed by a newly created folder, similar to how the post page is.
I'm guessing this error is due to my tinkering around with the config.yml file, while attempting to add something to `Collections`, but I do not know for sure. I'm new to jekyll and ruby environments and any guidance and support and further questions will be very much appreciated and very helpful.

Thank you!

Comment: Looks like the issue is from a custom plugin you have trying to access `relative_directory` on an undefined collection. As for why, could you provide a public GitHub repo? Otherwise the contents of `_config.yml` would also be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

here's my `_config.yml` file:

```
include:             ['_pages']
exclude:             ['_includes/notes_graph.json']
# You may need to change the base URL depending on your deploy configuration.
# Specifically, when using GitHub Pages, the baseurl should point to where GitHub
# Pages deploys your repository (which is usually the repository name).
baseurl:             ''

# If you are using a host that cannot resolve URLs that do
# not end with .html (such as Neocities), set this to 'true'.
use_html_extension:  false

# Set to `true` to open non-internal links in new tabs, or
# set to `false` to open non-internal links in current tab.
open_external_links_in_new_tab: true

permalink:           pretty
relative_permalinks: false

plugins:
  - jekyll-last-modified-at

sass:
  sass_dir:          _sass
  style:            :compressed

collections:
  writing: 
    output: true 
    permalink: /:slug

    
defaults:
  - scope:
      path: "**/*"
    values:
      layout: "default"
  - scope:
      path: "_notes/**/*.md"
    values:
      layout: "note"

assets:
   sources:
     -_assets/fonts/fraunces
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).